# R: Keep number of open issues by date

Tags: sql, r, date

My data is just 2 columns -- when something started and day it started on
I want to keep a running total of the number of things open.

For example, here is my data:

```
Issue      Day Started  Day Stopped
A          7-01-2013    Still Open
B          7-04-2013    7-06-2013
C          7-09-2013    7-10-2013
D          7-09-2013    7-11-2013
E          7-09-2013    Still Open
F          7-11-2013    Still Open
```

This is what I would like my data to look like:

```
Date       Issues Open
7-01-2013  1
7-02-2013  1
7-03-2013  1
7-04-2013  2
7-05-2013  2
7-06-2013  1
7-07-2013  1
7-08-2013  1
7-09-2013  4
7-10-2013  3
7-11-2013  3
```

Any tips on how to get this? Thanks!

Comment: sql or r? which solution are you looking for? if sql, tag the dbms you are using.

Comment: You can try my solution ~ I am not sure if there are more neat way.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df=='Still Open']='3000-01-01'# small trick
df$Day.Started=as.Date(df$Day.Started)
df$Day.Stopped=as.Date(df$Day.Stopped)
df1=data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2013/07/01"), by = "day", length.out = 20))

df1['Issues Open']=NA

for (i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){

    df1$`Issues Open`[i]=sum(df$Day.Started<=df1$Date[i]&df$Day.Stopped>df1$Date[i])
}

> df1
         Date Issues Open
1  2013-07-01           1
2  2013-07-02           1
3  2013-07-03           1
4  2013-07-04           2
5  2013-07-05           2
6  2013-07-06           1
7  2013-07-07           1
8  2013-07-08           1
9  2013-07-09           4
10 2013-07-10           3
11 2013-07-11           3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Wen` for pointing out my original answer was not answering OP's request. I wanted to add the obligate tidyverse answer:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

DF$Stopped[is.na(DF$Stopped)] <- max(DF$Started)+1
DF %>% 
   group_by( Issue ) %>% 
   nest() %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, ~ seq(.x$Started, .x$Stopped-1, 1))) %>% 
   unnest() %>%
   group_by(data) %>% 
   summarise(OpenIssues=sum(!is.na(Issue)))
```

Comment: this is not what OP wanted

Comment: Could you clarify what OP wanted?

Comment: Open case count , base on your Data, at 2017-01-03 there should have 6 case still open

Comment: In my data there are only **3** `2017-01-03` entries...how could there be **6** cases still open for this date? (Note that OP did not provide all of the `input` data that corresponds to the output.)

Comment: Case start at  2017-01-01  and 2017-01-02 not finish before 2017-01-03.

Comment: It's definitely not cumulative over dates...see OP's output. `1 1 1 2 2 1 1...`

Comment: it is ,cause some case are closed, then it will be removed from the count

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You are Welcome